# rinkeby balance says 0 after syncing even though transaction shows ether was sent

Tags: truffle, accounts, rinkeby

I'm using `truffle` to deploy a contract on the `rinkeby testnet`

Here is transaction info saying that my address received ether however as shown below, the balance still shows as 0.

```
    truffle(rinkeby)> web3.eth.getTransaction("0x4979d45cb9cf0959a9f2a139eb7adc6a231b866cc52289287bb2dd5b125b0635")
{ blockHash: '0xdf597f365e50a92bf3edbd37fc293f40d174b1c0a9b6d7a2cfb4df8c785126cb',
  blockNumber: 1759853,
  from: '0x31b98d14007bdee637298086988a0bbd31184523',
  gas: 21000,
  gasPrice: BigNumber { s: 1, e: 9, c: [ 1000008601 ] },
  hash: '0x4979d45cb9cf0959a9f2a139eb7adc6a231b866cc52289287bb2dd5b125b0635',
  input: '0x',
  nonce: 56835,
  to: '0x9c1a6ce6a1a5f6c80390977c9c9f653ff49a8729',
  transactionIndex: 2,
  value: BigNumber { s: 1, e: 19, c: [ 187500 ] },
  v: '0x2b',
  r: '0xbffa1a59cd0622b265d656bd9aad9a83bdc536ce1ba8b85af5d194ba93c56905',
  s: '0x43ef0187a715be575081e6a96c860b264cfb0a0007645b7267d5bca6535f213c' }
```

When seeing balance, it shows as 0:

```
truffle(rinkeby)> web3.eth.getBalance("0x9c1a6ce6a1a5f6c80390977c9c9f653ff49a8729")
BigNumber { s: 1, e: 0, c: [ 0 ] }
```

In etherscan it shows that there is a balance of 18 ether for the account:
`https://www.rinkeby.io/#explorer`

This is the geth command I'm using:

```
geth --rinkeby --rpc --rpcapi db,eth,net,web3,personal --rpcaddr 172.17.0.2 --unlock 9c1a6ce6a1a5f6c80390977c9c9f653ff49a8729
```

And it's synced to the newest block.

When I try and deploy the contract with the following command, it says:

```
    root@b91a643434cf:/voteApp# truffle migrate --network rinkeby
Using network 'rinkeby'.

Running migration: 1_initial_migration.js
  Deploying Migrations...
  ... undefined
Error encountered, bailing. Network state unknown. Review successful transactions manually.
Error: insufficient funds for gas * price + value
```

Comment: What is your truffle.js configuration file? Perhaps you are not using the correct address to deploy the contracts.

Answer (score 0):

following this tutorial fixed this: http://blog.jaumesola.com/setting-up-an-ethereum-node-on-the-rinkeby-testnet

Specifically:

> intitalise with genesis block
>
> $ curl -O https://www.rinkeby.io/rinkeby.json $ geth --datadir=. init
>   rinkeby.json load blockchain
>
> $ geth --networkid=4 --datadir=. --ethstats='yournode:Respect my
>   authoritah!@stats.rinkeby.io'
>   --bootnodes=enode://a24ac7c5484ef4ed0c5eb2d36620ba4e4aa13b8c84684e1b4aab0cebea2ae45cb4d375b77eab56516d34bfbd3c1a833fc51296ff084b770b94fb9028c4d25ccf@52.169.42.101:30303?discport=30304
>   --cache=1024 Wait. You will see the INFO message "Block synchronisation started" then many INFO lines starting with
>   "Imported...". Sync is in progress...
>
> Note the 1GB cache, you can use less or more depending on your
>   available memory Network id 4 corresponds to the Rinkeby chain
>   Blockchain data will be stored in geth/ Check blockchain sync progress
>   While the node is up & running (the above command) you can get info
>   about the blockchain sync progress (among other data) through the
>   JavaScript console. In another terminal window type:
>
> $ cd /path/to/rinkeby $ geth attach ipc:geth.ipc At the ">" prompt you
>   can type, e.g.
>
> > eth
> >     eth.syncing
> >     adm
> >     adm.peers